# method to take string inside curly braces using split or tokenizer

Tags: java, string, split, stringtokenizer

```
String s = "author= {insert text here},";
```

Trying to get the **inside** of the string, ive looked around but couldn't find a resolution with just split or tokenizer...

so far im doing this

```
arraySplitBracket = s.trim().split("\\{", 0);
```

which gives me  `insert text here}`,
at array[1] but id like a way to not have `}` attached

also tried

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "\\{,\\},");
```

But it gave me `author=`  as output.

Comment: can you clearly mention your input format?Does `s` and `author` refer to same variable ?
`author= {insert text here},` in this you have a comma so it is not clear what is the exact format of string you are assigning to `author`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: edited the s issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input="{a c df sdf TDUS^&%^7 }";     
        String regEx="(.*[{]{1})(.*)([}]{1})";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regEx).matcher(input);            

        if(matcher.matches()) {         
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
}
```

Comment: is there any way with just stringtokenizer or split? i feel it should be simpler ;o

Comment: Split or StringTokenizer can be used to Split the delimited string only. Here, since your case is a string bounded with curly braces, i hope it may not be helpful.

Comment: so if i were using split the only way would be to substring that string and do length()-2?arraySplitBracket[1].substring(0, arraySplitBracket[1].length()-2) this seems to work.

Comment: You may use substring if you want

Comment: Yes, as you said if you use split, you have to take substring ignoring the end curly braces

Comment: To be very simple, **input.substring(input.indexOf("{")+1,input.lastIndexOf("}"))**

Comment: thank you, what about stringtokenizer same issue as split?

Comment: Split or StringTokenizer . Both will be used in the case of fixed delimiter only.  if you use you have to take substring from last curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\\{([^}]*)\\}` Regex to get string between curly braces.

**Code Snap :**

```
String str = "{insert text here}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
          System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

**Output :**

```
insert text here
```

Comment: Can you please explain regex in detail

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "auther ={some text here},"; 
s =  s.substring(s.indexOf("{") + 1); //some text here},
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("}"));//some text here
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about taking a substring by excluding the character at `arraySplitBracket.length()-1`

Something like

```
arraySplitBracket[1] = arraySplitBracket[1].substring(0,arraySplitBracket.length()-1);
```

Or use String Class's replaceAll function to replace } ?